# Authentication is required error during automated build in docker hub

Tags: docker, bitbucket, dockerhub

I am trying to do an automated build from a private bitbucket repository. The automated build have been working before now but started giving errors this morning. Please help.

I have tried relinking the bitbucket repo and also deleted and recreated the automated build.

See the build log below.

````
Cloning into 'bfvya69v2qo7eevzf2mpncv'...
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '131.103.20.168' to the list of known hosts.
KernelVersion: 3.13.0-40-generic
Os: linux
BuildTime: Mon Oct 12 05:37:18 UTC 2015
ApiVersion: 1.20
Version: 1.8.3
GitCommit: f4bf5c7
Arch: amd64
GoVersion: go1.4.2
Step 0 : FROM dsninjas/sailsjs-base:1.5.2
Authentication is required.
```

I just realized that bitbucket is having some issues with ssh. I don't know if this could be the problem but might be useful information. 
http://status.bitbucket.org/incidents/n0bxvgvdbvdy

The issue has been logged on docker's status page. http://status.docker.com/pages/incident/533c6539221ae15e3f000031/564a0f6c455f8fe14a0003eb

The error just changed. It seems the automated build built successfully, but was unable to push to the docker hubs cloudfront endpoint. See the new log below.

To achieve this, i deleted my username from the owners team on the organization. Then added my username manually as an admin to the automated build repository.

```
---Truncated---
 ---> Running in aa5c1f6df2e2
 ---> 3fd2d5a1f032
Removing intermediate container aa5c1f6df2e2
Successfully built 3fd2d5a1f032
{"status":"The push refers to a repository [registry-1.docker.io/onecred/paylater-api] (len: 1)"}

{"status":"Buffering to Disk","progressDetail":{},"id":"3fd2d5a1f032"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":1,"total":32},"progress":"[=\u003e                                                 ]      1 B/32 B","id":"3fd2d5a1f032"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":32,"total":32},"progress":"[==================================================\u003e]     32 B/32 B","id":"3fd2d5a1f032"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":32,"total":32},"progress":"[==================================================\u003e]     32 B/32 B","id":"3fd2d5a1f032"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":32,"total":32},"progress":"[==================================================\u003e]     32 B/32 B","id":"3fd2d5a1f032"}
{"status":"Image successfully pushed","progressDetail":{},"id":"3fd2d5a1f032"}
{"status":"Buffering to Disk","progressDetail":{},"id":"de96a3bb2427"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":1,"total":32},"progress":"[=\u003e                                                 ]      1 B/32 B","id":"de96a3bb2427"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":32,"total":32},"progress":"[==================================================\u003e]     32 B/32 B","id":"de96a3bb2427"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":32,"total":32},"progress":"[==================================================\u003e]     32 B/32 B","id":"de96a3bb2427"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":32,"total":32},"progress":"[==================================================\u003e]     32 B/32 B","id":"de96a3bb2427"}
{"status":"Image successfully pushed","progressDetail":{},"id":"de96a3bb2427"}
{"status":"Buffering to Disk","progressDetail":{},"id":"28e1072fd16c"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":32769,"total":178905},"progress":"[=========\u003e                                         ] 32.77 kB/178.9 kB","id":"28e1072fd16c"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":65537,"total":178905},"progress":"[==================\u003e                                ] 65.54 kB/178.9 kB","id":"28e1072fd16c"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":98305,"total":178905},"progress":"[===========================\u003e                       ] 98.31 kB/178.9 kB","id":"28e1072fd16c"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":131073,"total":178905},"progress":"[====================================\u003e              ] 131.1 kB/178.9 kB","id":"28e1072fd16c"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":163841,"total":178905},"progress":"[=============================================\u003e     ] 163.8 kB/178.9 kB","id":"28e1072fd16c"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":178905,"total":178905},"progress":"[==================================================\u003e] 178.9 kB/178.9 kB","id":"28e1072fd16c"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":178905,"total":178905},"progress":"[==================================================\u003e] 178.9 kB/178.9 kB","id":"28e1072fd16c"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":178905,"total":178905},"progress":"[==================================================\u003e] 178.9 kB/178.9 kB","id":"28e1072fd16c"}
{"status":"Image successfully pushed","progressDetail":{},"id":"28e1072fd16c"}
{"status":"Buffering to Disk","progressDetail":{},"id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":294913,"total":28404143},"progress":"[\u003e                                                  ] 294.9 kB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":589825,"total":28404143},"progress":"[=\u003e                                                 ] 589.8 kB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":884737,"total":28404143},"progress":"[=\u003e                                                 ] 884.7 kB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":1179649,"total":28404143},"progress":"[==\u003e                                                ]  1.18 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":1474561,"total":28404143},"progress":"[==\u003e                                                ] 1.475 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":1769473,"total":28404143},"progress":"[===\u003e                                               ] 1.769 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":2064385,"total":28404143},"progress":"[===\u003e                                               ] 2.064 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":2359297,"total":28404143},"progress":"[====\u003e                                              ] 2.359 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":2654209,"total":28404143},"progress":"[====\u003e                                              ] 2.654 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":2949121,"total":28404143},"progress":"[=====\u003e                                             ] 2.949 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":3244033,"total":28404143},"progress":"[=====\u003e                                             ] 3.244 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":3538945,"total":28404143},"progress":"[======\u003e                                            ] 3.539 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":3833857,"total":28404143},"progress":"[======\u003e                                            ] 3.834 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":4128769,"total":28404143},"progress":"[=======\u003e                                           ] 4.129 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":4423681,"total":28404143},"progress":"[=======\u003e                                           ] 4.424 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":4718593,"total":28404143},"progress":"[========\u003e                                          ] 4.719 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":5013505,"total":28404143},"progress":"[========\u003e                                          ] 5.014 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":5308417,"total":28404143},"progress":"[=========\u003e                                         ] 5.308 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":5603329,"total":28404143},"progress":"[=========\u003e                                         ] 5.603 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":5898241,"total":28404143},"progress":"[==========\u003e                                        ] 5.898 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":6193153,"total":28404143},"progress":"[==========\u003e                                        ] 6.193 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":6488065,"total":28404143},"progress":"[===========\u003e                                       ] 6.488 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":6782977,"total":28404143},"progress":"[===========\u003e                                       ] 6.783 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":7077889,"total":28404143},"progress":"[============\u003e                                      ] 7.078 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":7372801,"total":28404143},"progress":"[============\u003e                                      ] 7.373 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":7667713,"total":28404143},"progress":"[=============\u003e                                     ] 7.668 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":7962625,"total":28404143},"progress":"[==============\u003e                                    ] 7.963 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":8257537,"total":28404143},"progress":"[==============\u003e                                    ] 8.258 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":8552449,"total":28404143},"progress":"[===============\u003e                                   ] 8.552 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":8847361,"total":28404143},"progress":"[===============\u003e                                   ] 8.847 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":9142273,"total":28404143},"progress":"[================\u003e                                  ] 9.142 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":9437185,"total":28404143},"progress":"[================\u003e                                  ] 9.437 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":9732097,"total":28404143},"progress":"[=================\u003e                                 ] 9.732 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":10027009,"total":28404143},"progress":"[=================\u003e                                 ] 10.03 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":10321921,"total":28404143},"progress":"[==================\u003e                                ] 10.32 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":10616833,"total":28404143},"progress":"[==================\u003e                                ] 10.62 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":10911745,"total":28404143},"progress":"[===================\u003e                               ] 10.91 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":11206657,"total":28404143},"progress":"[===================\u003e                               ] 11.21 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":11501569,"total":28404143},"progress":"[====================\u003e                              ]  11.5 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":11796481,"total":28404143},"progress":"[====================\u003e                              ]  11.8 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":12091393,"total":28404143},"progress":"[=====================\u003e                             ] 12.09 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":12386305,"total":28404143},"progress":"[=====================\u003e                             ] 12.39 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":12681217,"total":28404143},"progress":"[======================\u003e                            ] 12.68 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":12976129,"total":28404143},"progress":"[======================\u003e                            ] 12.98 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":13271041,"total":28404143},"progress":"[=======================\u003e                           ] 13.27 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":13565953,"total":28404143},"progress":"[=======================\u003e                           ] 13.57 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":13860865,"total":28404143},"progress":"[========================\u003e                          ] 13.86 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":14155777,"total":28404143},"progress":"[========================\u003e                          ] 14.16 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":14450689,"total":28404143},"progress":"[=========================\u003e                         ] 14.45 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":14745601,"total":28404143},"progress":"[=========================\u003e                         ] 14.75 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":15040513,"total":28404143},"progress":"[==========================\u003e                        ] 15.04 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":15335425,"total":28404143},"progress":"[==========================\u003e                        ] 15.34 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":15630337,"total":28404143},"progress":"[===========================\u003e                       ] 15.63 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":15925249,"total":28404143},"progress":"[============================\u003e                      ] 15.93 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":16220161,"total":28404143},"progress":"[============================\u003e                      ] 16.22 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":16515073,"total":28404143},"progress":"[=============================\u003e                     ] 16.52 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":16809985,"total":28404143},"progress":"[=============================\u003e                     ] 16.81 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":17104897,"total":28404143},"progress":"[==============================\u003e                    ]  17.1 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":17399809,"total":28404143},"progress":"[==============================\u003e                    ]  17.4 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":17694721,"total":28404143},"progress":"[===============================\u003e                   ] 17.69 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":17989633,"total":28404143},"progress":"[===============================\u003e                   ] 17.99 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":18284545,"total":28404143},"progress":"[================================\u003e                  ] 18.28 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":18579457,"total":28404143},"progress":"[================================\u003e                  ] 18.58 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":18874369,"total":28404143},"progress":"[=================================\u003e                 ] 18.87 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":19169281,"total":28404143},"progress":"[=================================\u003e                 ] 19.17 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":19464193,"total":28404143},"progress":"[==================================\u003e                ] 19.46 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":19759105,"total":28404143},"progress":"[==================================\u003e                ] 19.76 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":20054017,"total":28404143},"progress":"[===================================\u003e               ] 20.05 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":20348929,"total":28404143},"progress":"[===================================\u003e               ] 20.35 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":20643841,"total":28404143},"progress":"[====================================\u003e              ] 20.64 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":20938753,"total":28404143},"progress":"[====================================\u003e              ] 20.94 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":21233665,"total":28404143},"progress":"[=====================================\u003e             ] 21.23 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":21528577,"total":28404143},"progress":"[=====================================\u003e             ] 21.53 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":21823489,"total":28404143},"progress":"[======================================\u003e            ] 21.82 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":22118401,"total":28404143},"progress":"[======================================\u003e            ] 22.12 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":22413313,"total":28404143},"progress":"[=======================================\u003e           ] 22.41 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":22708225,"total":28404143},"progress":"[=======================================\u003e           ] 22.71 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":23003137,"total":28404143},"progress":"[========================================\u003e          ]    23 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":23298049,"total":28404143},"progress":"[=========================================\u003e         ]  23.3 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":23592961,"total":28404143},"progress":"[=========================================\u003e         ] 23.59 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":23887873,"total":28404143},"progress":"[==========================================\u003e        ] 23.89 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":24182785,"total":28404143},"progress":"[==========================================\u003e        ] 24.18 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":24477697,"total":28404143},"progress":"[===========================================\u003e       ] 24.48 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":24772609,"total":28404143},"progress":"[===========================================\u003e       ] 24.77 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":25067521,"total":28404143},"progress":"[============================================\u003e      ] 25.07 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":25362433,"total":28404143},"progress":"[============================================\u003e      ] 25.36 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":25657345,"total":28404143},"progress":"[=============================================\u003e     ] 25.66 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":25952257,"total":28404143},"progress":"[=============================================\u003e     ] 25.95 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":26247169,"total":28404143},"progress":"[==============================================\u003e    ] 26.25 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":26542081,"total":28404143},"progress":"[==============================================\u003e    ] 26.54 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":26836993,"total":28404143},"progress":"[===============================================\u003e   ] 26.84 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":27131905,"total":28404143},"progress":"[===============================================\u003e   ] 27.13 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":27426817,"total":28404143},"progress":"[================================================\u003e  ] 27.43 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":27721729,"total":28404143},"progress":"[================================================\u003e  ] 27.72 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":28016641,"total":28404143},"progress":"[=================================================\u003e ] 28.02 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":28311553,"total":28404143},"progress":"[=================================================\u003e ] 28.31 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":28404143,"total":28404143},"progress":"[==================================================\u003e]  28.4 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":28404143,"total":28404143},"progress":"[==================================================\u003e]  28.4 MB/28.4 MB","id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Image successfully pushed","progressDetail":{},"id":"e190f64bd30f"}
{"status":"Buffering to Disk","progressDetail":{},"id":"fca8e78f5a11"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":756,"total":756},"progress":"[==================================================\u003e]    756 B/756 B","id":"fca8e78f5a11"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":756,"total":756},"progress":"[==================================================\u003e]    756 B/756 B","id":"fca8e78f5a11"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":756,"total":756},"progress":"[==================================================\u003e]    756 B/756 B","id":"fca8e78f5a11"}
{"status":"Image successfully pushed","progressDetail":{},"id":"fca8e78f5a11"}
{"status":"Buffering to Disk","progressDetail":{},"id":"507fb46b20c9"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":384,"total":384},"progress":"[==================================================\u003e]    384 B/384 B","id":"507fb46b20c9"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":384,"total":384},"progress":"[==================================================\u003e]    384 B/384 B","id":"507fb46b20c9"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":384,"total":384},"progress":"[==================================================\u003e]    384 B/384 B","id":"507fb46b20c9"}
{"status":"Image successfully pushed","progressDetail":{},"id":"507fb46b20c9"}
{"status":"Buffering to Disk","progressDetail":{},"id":"2e0ee8501a36"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":191,"total":191},"progress":"[==================================================\u003e]    191 B/191 B","id":"2e0ee8501a36"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":191,"total":191},"progress":"[==================================================\u003e]    191 B/191 B","id":"2e0ee8501a36"}
{"status":"Pushing","progressDetail":{"current":191,"total":191},"progress":"[==================================================\u003e]    191 B/191 B","id":"2e0ee8501a36"}
{"errorDetail":{"message":"Head https://dseasb33srnrn.cloudfront.net/registry-v2/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/d6/d65fcbca9ac14737fe7be24321bb1eb929059297770e12f65a12df76854908bf/data?Expires=1447750540\u0026Signature=Vv03wbetWaDByZ40k3DD5RqCnV-XN2pbGPuuNlB~Hsb4Q~cXayWpcyjHeGdJlCS-LkMrVrjlM6VmIItMHUveghAkgRyMLvjF980wmotu09ff1YrnpUKnN43V4SICMgXFeihXcDCQxeRolhD73l8z5mMIfOmdngEWtmNO6O3Roas_\u0026Key-Pair-Id=APKAJECH5M7VWIS5YZ6Q: dial tcp 54.192.194.90:443: i/o timeout"},"error":"Head https://dseasb33srnrn.cloudfront.net/registry-v2/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/d6/d65fcbca9ac14737fe7be24321bb1eb929059297770e12f65a12df76854908bf/data?Expires=1447750540\u0026Signature=Vv03wbetWaDByZ40k3DD5RqCnV-XN2pbGPuuNlB~Hsb4Q~cXayWpcyjHeGdJlCS-LkMrVrjlM6VmIItMHUveghAkgRyMLvjF980wmotu09ff1YrnpUKnN43V4SICMgXFeihXcDCQxeRolhD73l8z5mMIfOmdngEWtmNO6O3Roas_\u0026Key-Pair-Id=APKAJECH5M7VWIS5YZ6Q: dial tcp 54.192.194.90:443: i/o timeout"}
````

Comment: I'm having this same problem with a build that works vs a private github repository and has a `FROM` to a public dockerhub image.

Comment: I received an update from my ticket that they are aware and working on the issue.

Comment: http://status.docker.com/ now shows Network Errors. The previous problem may be fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should open a support ticket with them.

I am currently experiencing this issue as well with public repos depending on other public images (no auth should be required). I submitted one last week for similar issues and got the following response for that:

> Our Automated Builds Team released a major update this weekend. However, this has affected the build details information when the automated build is failing. The builds that are failing are not getting proper error messages. We are working to resolve this issue as soon as possible and we will keep you updated. You can also track the status of Docker Hub Automated Builds here: http://status.docker.com/.

This may be related to them working on patching issues. I have commented on my Open issue to get more info. Opening support tickets would be the best way to notify them of the issue and get 1st hand feedback.

You can do that by going to the upper-right hand corner in dockerhub, clicking on your profile and going to "Help". Then choose the "Support" button. You may have to create an account with them.

If I hear anything back myself I'll try to post here.